# Margins on two-sided documents using LyX

Tags: lyx, margins, double-sided

I have an issue trying to set my margins on LyX.
I am using a two-sided document, the box for this option is checked. 
I've set the value of inner margins (4cm) and outer margins (2cm), but on my Pdf I always have my 4 cm margin on the left and the 2cm one on the right...

Any Idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Menu <kbd>Document</kbd> ⇢  <kbd>Configuration</kbd> ⇢<kbd>Documment class</kbd> ⇢ <kbd>Option class</kbd> ⇢ Write  here the  `twoside` option, so after fix the margins, the LaTeX source show something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,english,twoside]{article}
...
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=2cm}
```

Then add some content and *voilá*.

If you want reproduce this minimal working example (MWE), it is a default document (`article`) with an ERT box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) with `\lipsum[1-50]` to make  the dummy text. This need the package `lipsum`: <kbd>Document</kbd> ⇢  <kbd>Configuration</kbd> ⇢<kbd>LaTeX preamble</kbd> ⇢ Write  `\usepackage{lipsum}`. So this simple document:

[image]

will produce this LaTeX source:

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see ttp://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twocolumn,english,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=2cm}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\providecommand{\LyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{Made with \LyX{}}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The thing is I have already written my whole 50 pages work report, including floats and many other items ...

Comment: I manages to fix it. There was a class document, inwhich was wrtitten
twoside=semi. I editted it and wrote: twoside=on.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

From

> "Document" --> "Setting" ---> "Page Layout"

then click checkbox

> "Two-sided document".